# Disabling modules of PayaraMicro at startup

Tags: payara-micro

Is it possible to disable internal modules at startup, for example,
Hazelcast, to allow a faster boot of the app? I need this in development time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast can be easily disabled by the `--nocluster` command line option. There's no easy way to disable other services on command line - though most of them aren't started unless deployed applications need them.

When disabling Hazelcast, note that some services depend on it and wouldn't work. For example distributed CDI event bus, persistent timers, integrated JCache resources.